# sugarcrm retrieve accounts list in a web page using webservice

Tags: sugarcrm

I would like to retrieve all accounts datas  and contact datas in Sugarcrm database using webservice .

I would like it to show it in a webpage .

How can i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below code to your requirements. It uses the SOAP API of SugarCRM.

```
$user_name      = 'admin';
$user_password  = 'admin';
$sugarcrm_url   = 'http://example.com/'
$options = array(
  "uri" => $sugarcrm_url,
  "trace" => true
);

$offset = 0;
$limit  = 100;

try {
  $client = new SoapClient($sugarcrm_url.'service/v4_1/soap.php?wsdl', $options);

  $response = $client->__soapCall('login',array(
    'user_auth'=>array(
      'user_name'=>$user_name,
      'password'=>md5($user_password), 
      'version'=>'.01'
    ), 
    'application_name'=>'SoapTest'
  ));
  $session_id = $response->id;

  $response = $client->__soapCall('get_entry_list',array(
    'session'=>$session_id,
    'module_name'=>'Contacts',
    'query'=>'',
    'order_by'=>'contacts.last_name asc',
    'offset'=>$offset, 
    'select_fields'=>array(), 
    'max_results'=>$limit)
  );
  print_r($response);

  $response = $client->__soapCall('get_entry_list',array(
    'session'=>$session_id,
    'module_name'=>'Accounts',
    'query'=>'',
    'order_by'=>'accounts.name asc',
    'offset'=>$offset, 
    'select_fields'=>array('id', 'name', 'email1'), 
    'max_results'=>$limit)
  );
  print_r($response);

  $response = $client->__soapCall('logout',array('session'=>$session_id));

} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```